# in javascript if arrays, functions are objects prototypes then why typeof returns

Tags: javascript, typeof

in javascript if arrays, functions are objects prototypes then why typeof returns object for a variable that holds an array and it returns Function for a variable that holds a reference to a function.

Comment: Do you mean `typeof` or `instanceof`? Because this `Boolean(function(){} instanceof Object)` is true.

Comment: sorry I meant typeof, I have edit the message body

Comment: `typeof` always returns `string`.

Comment: Well, there is a catch-all answer for questions like "why in javascript <some weird kind of thing>?" - because they had only ten days to create it. Just like the world we live in.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the ECMAScript 3.0 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) (Pages 46 - 47):

> **11.4.3 The typeof Operator**
>
> The production UnaryExpression : **typeof** UnaryExpression is
>   evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Evaluate UnaryExpression.
> 2. If Type(Result(1)) is not Reference, go to step 4.
> 3. If GetBase(Result(1)) is **null**, return **"undefined"**.
> 4. Call GetValue(Result(1)).
> 5. Return a string determined by Type(Result(4)) according to the following table:

```
Type                                              Result
Undefined                                         "undefined"
Null                                              "object"
Boolean                                           "boolean"
Number                                            "number"
String                                            "string"
Object (native and doesn’t implement [[Call]])    "object"
Object (native and implements [[Call]])           "function"
Object (host)                                     Implementation-dependent
```

I couldn't find any reference to `typeof` in the 1.0 specification, and while wikipedia references a 2.0 specification, I couldn't find it online.

While [georg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989121/georg) makes a lovely sentiment, it would appear that the `typeof` unary operator was added to JavaScript sometime after the initial release (so some thought had to have been put into it).

That said, there are many ways around the limitations. Just google "[fixing typeof](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=fixing%20typeof)"... there's around 41.7 million results. :)